# Op amp with feedback

Tags: resistors, feedback, negative

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feyEN0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How to calculate Iout(current flowing through RL) of this circuit?
All Resistors are of same value except the load resistor.
Let the rail voltages be +15v and -15v.

Comment: You have deleted the component designators (R1, R2, etc.) making discussion of your circuit nearly impossible. Please edit the schematic, double-click each component and put the numbers back in.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Seems like a homework question to me. What have you done to try and solve this problem? We will help you but not do your homework for you.

Comment: This was asked in my today's interview at x company. I answered them, as it has positive feedback the output voltage will saturate to the rails and then apply ohms law at the output to calculate Iout. Is this correct?

Comment: Unless the R's are all the same value. And it does look like homework. Hints: how much current flows into the inputs of the (ideal) op-amp? If the voltage at the - input is V1, what must the voltage at the + input be?

Comment: Thank you for the reply guys. R's are of the same value. The ideal op-amp has an infinite input impedance, so no current flows through the inputs. Considering virtual ground voltages will be the same. for ideal opamp V1=V2(+ve terminal voltage)=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft42RE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's schematic redrawn with component designators and voltage reference points added.*

\$ V_- = \frac {R_1}{R_1 + R_2}V_O \tag 1\$.

Since R1 = R2 then \$ V_O = 2 V_- \tag 2\$.

If the op-amp is working in linear negative feedback mode then \$ V_- = V_+ \$ so \$ V_O = 2 V_+ \tag 3 \$.

Summing the currents into V<sub>+</sub> we get

$$ \begin{align} I_{RL} & = I_{R3} + I_{R4} \tag 4 \\
& = \frac {V_{IN} - V_{+}}{R3} + \frac{V_O - V_+}{R4} \tag 5 \\
& = \frac {V_{IN} - V_{+}}{R3} + \frac{2V_+ - V_+}{R4}  \tag 6 \\
& = \frac {V_{IN} - V_{+}}{R} + \frac{V_{+}}{R} \tag 7\\ 
& = \frac{ V_{IN}}{R} \tag 8
\end{align}
$$

Perhaps surprisingly the output current is independent of R<sub>L</sub>.

Note how difficult it would be to write these equations without the component designations requested in my comment to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I'm a new contributor so I was a little confused with the site interface and your comment.